# Create an Identity User Page for ASP.NET MVC Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I implement an ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework) identity, and the Registration Page and Login Authentication page were as expected auto-generated.

I would like to have a separate page though for List of REGISTERED USERS and this is what I have done.

1. Add Controller - MVC5 with Vies using Entity Framework to auto generate CRUD functionality.

[image]

Upon doing, I got this error > No Key is defined in the View Model

[image]

So I tried to add the Id Property in the model like this

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

      .... 
   }
```

But still get the same error.

Please advise

Comment: That's the wrong code generator because view models aren't stored in a database and  should not be.

Comment: I agree with @AluanHaddad that your  'model' should not be named 'view model', please check out how MVVM works. however you certainly can call your model anything you want, including 'viewmodel' and the generator should still work

Answer (score 0):

A primary key should uniquely identify a row. It is uncommon to use a string as a primary key.

If it indeed makes sense and the string IS the only unique identifier for your table, then you must let Entity Framework know that your key is not an identity column, because it by default tries to apply this property to the [Key] column.

> read more on IDENTITY in T-SQL
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15

```cs
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public string FooId { get; set; }
```

All that being said, you should probably go with an `integer` or `Guid`

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your property ID from string to integer

Comment: This is correct, but not completely correct. You can have a primary key be a string.